# Best way to unbind ido-dired in spacemacs

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I'm inclined to like spacemacs, but I'm not a fan of Ido, and I find it pretty offputting to drop into ido-dired when I type C-x d.  Is there a recommended way of preventing this?

Comment: Umm..bind it to something else?!

Comment: My cursory examination of ido.el suggests that ido grabs the 'dired' command and maps it to its own version, so tinkering with key bindings seems unlikely to be successful. As an experiment, I went into ido.el and just commented out the line where it hijacks dired. This works, but it's a little inelegant...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `dotspacemacs/user-config` I've added `(ido-mode 0)`. It's a pretty blunt instrument, but it seems to be doing the trick. I'll keep poking; perhaps there's a nice way of preventing ido from being loaded in the first place.